# Converting PDF to TIFF with ImageMagick shows UnableToOpenBlob

Tags: batch-file, pdf, imagemagick, tiff

I am trying to convert a PDF to a TIFF file for OCR with Tesseract. As of now, because I am running on Windows, I am trying to write the conversion as a batch file. This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
:start
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET IMCONV="C:\Program Files\ImageMagick\convert.exe"
set /p INPUTF=Input file(enter done if done)?
if %INPUTF%==done goto end
set /p OUTPUTF=Output file?

%IMCONV% -density 300 %INPUTF% -depth 8 %OUTPUTF%


goto start
:end
```

When I run this I get `convert.exe:UnableToOpenBlob` and that there is no file in directory `@error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695`. Any idea what's wrong?

---

After taking the advice from Mark Setchell the above problem has been fixed however now I receive the error `convert.exe: UnableToOpenConfigureFile 'delegates.xml' @warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/706`

Comment: What happens if you just type `"convert SomeFile.pdf SomeFile.jpg"` using the name of a PDF file you have on your PC? Have you installed ghostscript?

Comment: I get `Invalid Parameter - SomeFile.jpg`. I have not download ghostscript, do I need it or can I work solely from ImageMagick?

Comment: Internally, ImageMagick uses `ghostscript` to process PDF files so you will need to install that.

Comment: After downloading `ghostscript` is there an alternative syntax or should the same syntax work.

Comment: The same syntax should work. Make sure ImageMagick's `convert.exe` and Ghostscript's `gs.exe` are both on your PATH in Control Panel->System->Advanced->Environment Variables so that ImageMagick can find `gs.`exe`. Check the output of `identify -list configure` to see what DELEGATES you have installed.

Comment: I am still receiving the same error, `UnableToOpenBlob`, is my file supposed to be in a certain directory?

Comment: Start simple with the source and destination files in the working directory then build up from there.